# Query on RevenueForecast object does not return any results in test class

Tags: unit-test, forecast

How to get results from RevenueForecast object in a test class?
I created Opportunity, PricebookEntry, OpportunityLineItem and OpportunityLineItemSchedule objects. I expect to get a record from RevenueForecast object. How to do that?

This is the code taken from test method:

```
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
            opp.Name = 'Test';
            opp.CloseDate = Date.today();
            opp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
            insert opp;

            Product2 product = new Product2();
            product.Name = 'Laptop X200';
            product.Family = 'Hardware';
            product.CanUseRevenueSchedule = true;
            product.RevenueScheduleType = 'Repeat';
            product.NumberofRevenueInstallments = 12;
            product.RevenueInstallmentPeriod = 'Monthly';
            insert product;

            Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
            PricebookEntry priceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry();
            priceBookEntry.Pricebook2Id = pricebookId;
            priceBookEntry.Product2Id = product.Id;
            priceBookEntry.UnitPrice = 1000; 
            priceBookEntry.IsActive = true;
            insert priceBookEntry;

            OpportunityLineItem lineItem = new OpportunityLineItem();
            lineItem.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
            lineItem.PriceBookEntryId = priceBookEntry.Id;
            lineItem.Quantity = 1;
            lineItem.TotalPrice = 1000;
            insert lineItem;

            OpportunityLineItemSchedule schedule = new OpportunityLineItemSchedule();
            schedule.OpportunityLineItemId = lineItem.Id;
            schedule.Revenue = 1000;
            schedule.ScheduleDate = Date.today();
            schedule.Type = 'Revenue';
            insert schedule;

List<RevenueForecast> forecastList = [SELECT Id FROM RevenueForecast];
```

Comment: I note Opportunity is not associated to an Account

Comment: @cropredy I assigned Opportunity to Account but it does not help, I get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
```

must be added to test class. Also, new user must be created inside test method and test code surrounded by

```
System.runAs(testUser){
//test code here
}
```

Creating user for testing will ensure that Forecast data for user is not mixed with actual data appearing in org.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, can bring this tip to [Kaunas Salesforce Developer Group](https://www.meetup.com/Kaunas-Salesforce-Developer-Group/events/230823450/)? :)